# Change text on mousein/out with an array randomly?

Tags: jquery, arrays, random, mouseover, mouseout

I have very simple but frustrating problem. Basically what I'm trying to do is when you MouseIn & Out of a particular element then an elements text will change randomly through an array. Heres my code, starting with the HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="#">
        luke <span>whitehouse</span> 
    </a>
    <span class="logo-note">// front-end web designer</span>
</div>
```

And heres the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var quotes = new Array("foo", "bar", "baz", "chuck");
    var randno = Math.floor ( Math.random() * quotes.length );
    $('.quote').add(quotes[randno]);

    $('.logo a').mouseover(function() {
        $('.logo-note').text(quotes[randno]);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('.logo-note').text(quotes[randno]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the random text when the mouse over/out event occurs. In your code `randno` is calculated once and never changes so you'll keep getting the same array element everytime. Try this as an idea

```
$('.logo a').mouseover(function() {
        $('.logo-note').text(quotes[Math.floor ( Math.random() * quotes.length )]);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('.logo-note').text(quotes[Math.floor ( Math.random() * quotes.length )]);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Satyajit, thanks for your great response. This did fix the majority of the problem however the only problem now is that if there any child tags within the selector (in this case ".logo a" however I have changed some parts so its now just ".logo", then the script is run again and a new array number is found. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Can you explain that in some more detail? Maybe show your new HTML and how the requirement has changed. Sounds like for some elements you don't want a random text - is that it?

Comment: Hi Dude, i've created a codepen for you. Basically, when you hover over the .logo it works fine however, when you also hover over nested elements within this i.e the 'a' tag, it once again runs the script.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ovaHg